# Prefetch or Preload Typekit fonts

Tags: html, webfonts, prefetch, typekit

Has anyone tried successfully to reduce loading times of Typekit by using `preload` or `prefetch`? i.e.

```
<link rel='preload' href='...' as='font'>

<!-- and/or -->

<link rel='prefetch' href='...'>
```

Is it a practical or possible in the current Typekit loading setup?

Comment: Is the `as` part of some extension I don;t know about?

Comment: @MrLister  I saw it at or around slide 87 of https://speakerdeck.com/bramstein/web-fonts-performance

Comment: Ah, I see. with “” quotes too. Hm.

Answer (score 3):

You could try preloading Typekit's script:

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://use.typekit.net/[YOUR_KIT_ID].js" as="script">
```

I've tested this and it does seem to work. The 'loading order' of waterfall changes — the Typekit script moved up to tie second with my main (deferred) javascript file. As for performance, I'm not seeing much improvement — if any at all.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, [`link rel='preload'`](https://w3c.github.io/preload/) is not implemented by any browser.

I have tried using `link rel='prefetch'`, and Chrome did prefetch that font, however, it ignored the prefetched font and downloaded it again when it needed it.

Comment: Thanks @codener.   I guess Service Workers might be the eventual solution.  Perhaps appCache...